# Change sound pitch Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

So I was just on my laptop one day when I went on Youtube and the music went all high pitched. So I tried another few songs and their pitches had gone up too. Anyone want to help? If this is any help, the same day I tried to change my swappiness and that's when it started

Thanks in advance,

Stupot65

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but in 12.10 ubuntu gnome remix.
Spotify and VLC is fine but Youtube is high pitched.

Chocolate Rain on Youtube sounds normal instead of dark xD

---

EDIT:

If I go to "Sound" settings and choose random other option on settings then back to Analog Stereo Output the high pitch is gone, Chocolate Rain is again dark and nice. It usaually pitches back after a week or so.